# Sliding JPanel with Universal Tween Engine

Tags: animation, frameworks, jpanel, tween, universal

For a few days I have been trying to create a JPanel, that comes flying in from the side. I found the Universal Tween Engine and also saw a few demos but for some reason I was never able to make it work in my own code. For the sake of simplicity let's just attempt to move a JPanel (containing an image in a JLabel) from (0,0) to (600,0) on a JFrame. This is what I've got so far and the closest I have ever gotten to actually moving things with this framework, all it does it make the JPanel jump to its destination within the first tick or so. It is supposed to be so simple but I must be missing something...

`SlideTest.java` - Creating the UI, initializing the Thread + Tween

```
public class SlideTest {
    TweeningPane p;
    public TweenManager tweenManager;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SlideTest();
    }

    public SlideTest() {
        try {
            setupGUI();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        tweenManager = new TweenManager();
        AnimationThread aniThread = new AnimationThread();
        aniThread.setManager(tweenManager);
        aniThread.start();
        Tween.to(p, 1, 10.0f).target(600).ease(Quad.OUT).start(tweenManager);
    }

    public void setupGUI() throws IOException {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setSize(800, 600);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        p = new TweeningPane();
        JLabel l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("E:/Pictures/Stream/aK6IX4V.png"));
        f.setLayout(null);
        p.add(l);
        p.setBounds(0, 0, 300, 300);
        f.add(p);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

AnimationThread.java - The Thread, that is supposed to keep my TweenManager updated as much/often as possible

```
public class AnimationThread extends Thread {
    TweenManager tm;

    public void setManager(TweenManager tweenmanager) {
        this.tm = tweenmanager;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            //System.out.println("MyThread running");
            tm.update(MAX_PRIORITY);
            try {
                sleep(40);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

TweeningPane.java - My Object(JPanel), I want to move across the JPanel

```
public class TweeningPane extends JPanel implements TweenAccessor<JPanel> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public int getValues(JPanel arg0, int arg1, float[] arg2) {

        return (int) arg0.getBounds().getX();
    }

    @Override
    public void setValues(JPanel arg0, int arg1, float[] arg2) {
        arg0.setBounds((int) arg2[0], 0, 300, 300);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have finally figured it out. I was simply using the framework in a wrong way as I expected. I'm not sure whether all these steps were needed but this is what I went through in order to make it work: (for future reference)

I had to register my accessor to the engine:

```
Tween.registerAccessor(TweeningPane.class, new TweeningPane());
```

And the thread itself now looks like this; I had to give the manager's update method the elapsed time as a parameter.

```
public void run() {
    long ms1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (true) {
        //System.out.println("MyThread running");
        tm.update((System.currentTimeMillis() - ms1) / 1000f);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(40);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```